# Can you help me to find Omega, Theta, and Big O notations for the following equation?

Tags: asymptotics

Can you help me to find Omega, Theta, and Big O notations for the following equation?

$T(n)=\left(\frac{n+3}{n}\right)^n$

I have tried this, but I'm unsure if I'm moving in the right direction to solve it.

For Big-O notation..

$$0\leq T(n)\leq c \cdot g(n)$$

$$0\leq \left(\frac{n+3}{n}\right)^n \leq n^n$$

$$O(n^n) \forall n \geq 3$$

For $\Omega$ Notation..

$$0 \leq c\cdot g(n) \leq T(n) $$

$$ 0 \leq n^n \leq \left(\frac{n+3}{n}\right)^n$$

$$\Omega(n^n) \forall  0 < n < 3$$

Is it right? Help me with this.

Comment: $n^n \leq \left(\frac{n+3}{n}\right)^n$ ?????

Comment: Revise the definitions please and look at a couple of examples to understand what does these notations mean. You've written $\Omega(n^n) \forall  0 < n < 3$, but that's not how these notations work. We say functions are big O, small o,  big Omega, small omega and Theta $\textbf{asymptotically}$, which generally means that the conditions are true for $\textbf{large }$ $N$ (specifically $\forall n\ge n_0$ for some $n_0$)

Comment: Also that condition isn't even true for $0<n<3$, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/izefp6mnwh . Not that it matters here

Comment: @EnEm, I have recaptured the basics of asymptotic notations, but I'm still finding it hard to solve the $\Omega$ notation for this particular recurrence. Can you give a hint so that I can work on solving it?

Comment: How did you solve for the $\Theta$ notation?

Comment: @EnEm, using the limits that you mentioned earlier. Using this as a reference(https://web.mit.edu/broder/Public/asymptotics-cheatsheet.pdf). But the problem I'm facing is with the $n_{0}$ value for $\Omega$ notation.

Comment: So you were able to find $n_0,c_1,c_2$ such that $c_1g(n)\le f(n) \le c_2 g(n) :\forall n_0\ge n$ but can't find an $n_0,c$ such that $cg(n)\le f(n) \forall :n_0\ge n$ ??

Comment: @EmEn 
Oh shit, I'm yet to find c1, c2. I wrote the normal form for $\Theta$ notation. I made a mistake while finding $\Theta$ notation.

Comment: Ok, hint for all three $\Omega, O and \Theta$ , use $g(n) = 1$

Comment: @EnEm,
For $\Omega$, $(1+\frac{3}{n})^{n}>1$, $n_{0} \geq 1$ where $c$ is $1$. Therefore $\Omega(log n)$ Is this right? For $\Theta$ notation please look at this(https://www.desmos.com/calculator/spobjrazii)

Comment: $\Omega(1)$, Also you can't put $c_1 = 0$, it should be $>0$. Also your $c_2$ doesn't work for large n. Check this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lejfplt5am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your big O complexity is correct, it isn't the tightest bound, and hence you cannot get the Theta complexity using that.

The key hint is to use the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+3}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)^n=e^3$, using which you can prove that this is actually $\Theta(1)$

Comment: Hey @EnEm, can you please look at the Omega notation? Also, is there any way to find Theta notation without using limits?

Comment: @AmanRangapur Theta is just Omega + Big O, You cant get to Theta without Omega. With the limit Im not just finding out the Theta, Im also finding the Omega and big O, and using it you find the Theta. Revise the definitions for these notations once. For your second part, I guess you can just prove that T(n) is bounded and that would be enough, no need to show that it is converging too, and whats its converging to. You can do this by simply showing $T(n)\leq\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{3^k}{k!} \forall n$

Comment: @AmanRangapur Ohh you meant the edit you did in your original question, sorry I didn't see that. I'll respond it to now.